# Homotopy type of complex algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In his 1974 ICM adress "Poids dans la cohomologie des variétés algébriques", Pierre Deligne explains that any finite polyhedron has the same homotopy type as a complex algebraic variety (section 6.).

Let us take a finite polyhedron $P$, what obstructions do we know on $P$ in order to prove that $P$ has not the same homotopy type as a complete complex variety?

Edit: for example, we know that spheres $S^{2k}$ with $k>1$ cannot have the homotopy type of a smooth complete, complex algebraic space because for these spaces the second singular cohomology group $H^2\neq 0$. And for the same reason it cannot have the same homotopy type of a projective variety.

But can we prove that $S^{2k}$ cannot have the homotopy type of a possibly singular complete complex variety using cohomological arguments? In such generality we cannot use only $H^2$ because we know examples of complete nonprojective singular varieties with $H^2=0$.

Comment: Every complete variety is an oriented pseudomanifold. In particular, its top homology group is nonzero and has even degree. Thus, the circle is the simplest example of a compact CW complex which does not have homotopy type of a complete (complex) variety.

Comment: I agree this is certainly the very first obstruction to look at.

Comment: Can't you still say $H^2\neq 0$ if $X$ is singular? Because the inclusion of $X$ into a projective space is nontrivial in the top cohomology of $X$.

Comment: Dear Tom, you are right we can fix the case of projective varieties thanks to $H^2$. But I would like to have more general criteria that work also in the complete nonprojective case.

Comment: I am not sure about $H^2\ne 0$: Consider the examples of toric varieties in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176449/second-betti-number-of-compact-analytic-spaces.

Comment: Misha maybe I am missing something:
- Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}P^{N+n}$ a complex projective variety of dimension $n$, then the induced map in homology $H_{2n}(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_{2n}(\mathbb{C}P^{N+n})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is non-zero (intersecting $X$ with a general N-plane we get a finite set of points positively oriented).
- The dual map in cohomology in degree $2n$ is also non zero, 
- as the cohomology algebra of $\mathbb{C}P^{N+n}$ is generated by a class in $H^2$ we deduce that $H^2(X)\neq 0$.

Comment: Of course. I am concerned with the nonprojective case.

Comment: In the non-projective case I agree with you we can have $H^2=0$ (some nonprojective toric 3-folds). But do you know if a complete nonprojective 3-fold can have the same homotopy type as $S^6$?

Comment: No, I do not know but maybe one can prove that in this case it has to be homeomorphic to the 6-sphere... I do not know about 4-sphere either.

Comment: Since no one else has mentioned it: one obstruction is that $\pi_1(P)$ has to be a Kähler group.

Comment: @DanPetersen: $\pi_1(P)$ being a Kähler group is an obstruction in the smooth case, but not in the singular case. Kapovich has proved that every finitely-presented group can be realized as fundamental group of an irreducible complex-projective surface, cf. Dirichlet fundamental domains and topology of projective varieties, Invent. math. 194, 631-672, 2013. So in the singular case, there is no obstruction from the fundamental group.