# Homotopy groups of fiber products

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, riemannian-geometry

Let $X, Y, B$ be three smooth manifolds, and $f : X\to B$, $g : Y\to B$ submersions.

Then $X\times_BY$ exists.

> (1) If $X, Y, B$ have the homotopy type of a finite CW complex, does $X\times_BY$?
>
> (2) What is $\pi_n(X\times_BY)$ in relation to $\pi_n(X),\pi_n(Y),\pi_n(B)$?

Comment: I also wanted to know this,.

Answer (score 10):

Let $X\times_B Y$ denote the homotopy pullback in spaces of maps $X,Y\to B$. (It's not clear whether you mean the ordinary pullback or the homotopy pullback; if $X$ or $Y$ is compact, then $f$ or $g$ (respectively) will be a fibration, by Ehresmann's theorem; therefore, the homotopy pullback will agree with the ordinary pullback.) Then there is a fiber sequence $\Omega B \to X\times_B Y \to X\times Y$. This gives a long exact sequence 
$$\cdots \to \pi_k \Omega B = \pi_{k+1} B \to \pi_k(X\times_B Y) \to \pi_k(X\times Y) = \pi_k(X) \oplus \pi_k(Y) \to \pi_k B \to \cdots$$
Given $\pi_\ast(B),\pi_\ast(X)$, and $\pi_\ast(Y)$, you can use this to get at $\pi_\ast(X\times_B Y)$.

Comment: @John : Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542889/visualizing-a-homotopy-pull-back This is for reference of other users (including me :D).. there is a relation between homotopy pullback denoted by $X\times^h_BY$ and the pullback given in question denoted by $X\times_BY$..

Comment: Can you please give reference for “the fiber sequence $\Omega B\rightarrow X\times_BY\rightarrow X\times Y$”... I am assuming $\Omega B$ means loop space of $B$.. Just for confirmation, your $X\times_BY$ is the homotopy pullback and not the usual pullback...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik This is classical. For a reference, see, e.g., Proposition 3.2 here: http://people.math.binghamton.edu/malkiewich//fibration_sequences.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I read about homotopy pullback only recently. So I do not know what is classic and what is not.,, thanks for link... I will read,,,, :)

Comment: Thanks. I read about homotopy pullback only recently. So I do not know what is classic and what is not.,, thanks for link... I will read,,,, :)   I also found some reference. page no 14 of http://uregina.ca/~franklam/Math527/Math527_0308.pdf

Comment: Also relevant is my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3398/mayer-vietoris-homotopy-groups-sequence-of-a-pull-back-of-a-fibration/33113#33113